# Can I create a pull request template that is shared across our repositories?

Tags: azure-devops

We have several products developed in each their repositories. We use Azure DevOps for pull requests. We have a [Pull Request template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-templates) that we wish to use on all repositories, hopefully maintaining in a single spot.

Is that possible and how?

Comment: @AndersJuul does not seem like it but maybe at some point if you upvote in this [Developer Community thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Central-pull-request-template-for-multip/1655479?space=21&q=pull+request+template+from+other+repo)